# POS integration for Magento

Tags: pos

We bought POS system from the Bank and they provided us some sample codes(asp,c,php,vb).
They are not giving support for magento. We will use XMLPay (not 3D Payment)

Do i need a module for this?
İf we are doing integration by modules which one is the best for standard payments(mastercard,visa,amex).

Any information is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a payment module for this. Check Magento Connect to see if there is a module already made for your particular case and if not you might be able to use the PHP samples the Bank gave you to create your own module.